# Can't make API call memcache.Set in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I am trying to use google appengine memcache. But it gives the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call memcache.Set in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException.foreignThread(ApiProxy.java:800)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:175)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:172)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:89)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:89)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.put(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:79)
    at com.google.mem.rizvi.GoogleMemcacheForStories.MemcachedDemo.main(MemcachedDemo.java:16)
```

My simple sample code is given below:

## Users.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Users implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

## MemcachedDemo.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheService;
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceFactory;

public class MemcachedDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Users users = new Users();
        users.setId(1);
        users.setName("Sunil123");
        users.setId(2);
        users.setName("Rizvi");
        MemcacheService memcache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
        memcache.put("someKey_1",  users);
        Object myObject=memcache.get("someKey_1");
        System.out.println("Object 1: " + myObject);
        System.out.println("Statistics: " + memcache.getStatistics());
        memcache.delete("someKey_2");
        memcache.clearAll();
        memcache=null ;
    }
}
```

I have got that as google sdk is not open source. so it will not give proper access.

Same issue is asked here also: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues/749

Is there any workaround to use google memcache?

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't use memcache from a main method, you can use it if you have a GAE server running and you do the memcache call as part of serving one of the requests to it.

Just put your demo code in a servlet or a jsp run the server call it, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to what @montss said, com.google.appengine.api.memcache can only be used with App Engine Standard. At the moment you can only access to memcache from App Engine Flex via this [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfGMYNeKC0G5aw6GEiocL1DjT2H5AFUCqsbxoerfuj3Y1rHxw/viewform?c=0&w=1) as the feature is in Alpha.

I'd recommend to go through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/memcache/examples), run you code in a [Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server) and/or using a difference caching library.